# Add the results of two calculated columns

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I need some help with a proximity search.  I need to run a select statement on a real estate property database to determine the top rows (a number input by the user) that are closest to the search criteria.  I then need to display these values in a gridview control.

What I can't figure out is how to add the values of multiple calculated columns to create one final column with the proximity result.

Can someone help me figure out how to sum multiple calculated columns into one column, then group by this column?

Below is the code I tried but get an error exception.

```
aQueryString = "SELECT Top " + txtNumRows.Text;
aQueryString += "propno, ";

if (txtMaxAsk.Text != "")
    aQueryString += "askprice, ";

aQueryString += "sqr(((askprice - " + txtMaxAsk.Text;
aQueryString += ")/1000000)^2) AS m1,";

if (txtMinSqFt.Text != "")
    aQueryString += "sqft, ";

aQueryString += "sqr(((sqft - " + txtMinSqFt.Text;
aQueryString += ")/6000)^2) AS m2 ";
aQueryString += "sum(m1) + sum(m2) FROM property ORDER BY 4 ";

anAccessCommand = anAccessConnection.CreateCommand();
anAccessCommand.CommandText = aQueryString;
gvProperty.DataSource = anAccessCommand.CommandText;
anAccessReader = anAccessCommand.ExecuteReader();
gvProperty.DataSource = anAccessReader;
gvProperty.Visible = true;

try
{
    gvProperty.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("Binding exception in Button1_Click<BR>");
    Response.Write("Access Exception Handler: {0} " + ex.ToString());
}
```

This is the OleDbException I get:

`The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.`

Comment: aQueryString += ")/6000)^2) AS m2 should be aQueryString += ")/6000)^2) AS m2, at a guess. Put a debug on aQueryString. Oh and you are open to a sql injection attack..

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma at the end of this line:

```
aQueryString += ")/6000)^2) AS m2 ";
```

Corrected:

```
aQueryString += ")/6000)^2) AS m2, ";
```